# R mice package pooling function not pooling after using as.factor?

Tags: r, r-factor, r-mice

data:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

I'm trying to use the mice package on a data set after applying as.factor

```
train_df<-data.frame(read.csv("train.csv", header = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    source="train"
    ))
train_df$MSSubClass<- as.factor(train_df$MSSubClass)
imp_train_df <-mice(train_df, m=2, method='cart')
reg1 <- with(imp_train_df, lm(SalePrice ~ MSSubClass))
head(summary(pool(reg1))$term)
```

**I end up getting something like:**

```
[1] (Intercept)  MSSubClass30 MSSubClass40 MSSubClass45 MSSubClass50 MSSubClass60
316 Levels: (Intercept) MSSubClass30 MSSubClass40 MSSubClass45 MSSubClass50 MSSubClass60 MSSubClass70 MSSubClass75 MSSubClass80 MSSubClass85 MSSubClass90 ... SaleConditionPartial
```

This seems to be computing the p value for each factor in the column, but I am only interested in the entire column.

**where I'm actually expecting:**
`MSSubClass`

*What did I do wrong?*

Comment: It is not caused by as.factor -> it's caused by MICE